# Android webview audio recording does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Voice recorder does not work in my webview application, which I write with Java. Please help. I don't know how to get a voice recording permit.
here is my code:

her is the complete code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ov5BesMJN7aXF9IGA-mJO0FObIqH4pWr/view?usp=sharing

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Connection.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            finish();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
                try {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                }
            }

            else {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return false;
```

Comment: show your code pls

Comment: I added the code

Comment: @EmirhanBülbül, is your issue resolved? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need runtime permission to allow voice recording here is the code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // put your code for Version>=Marshmallow
    } else {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "App required access to audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        }, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
    }

} else {
    // put your code for Version < Marshmallow
}
```

and override onRequestPermissionsResult

```js
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

  if (requestCode == REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Application will not have audio on record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've applied the permission window comes out I give approval, but this warning comes out   https://prnt.sc/rov1gm

Comment: just press ok then see what happens ?

Comment: thanks to the codes you sent, the permission screen came first, but then this warning came.

Comment: after permission screen did u allow or denied ? if allowed then it must work.please let me know

Comment: I gave permission after permission screen and gave this warning "please allow microphone access"

Comment: this screen when the application opens https://prnt.sc/rovj97 coming through. I confirm. But when you click on the sound recording button, it gives an error.

Comment: can you paste what error shown from logcat so that i can trace what is exact problem ?

Comment: click on the ok button "2020-03-29 20:50:48.965 12694-12732/com.kal.bizde D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc207ce00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xc86da920
2020-03-29 20:50:49.002 12694-12732/com.kal.bizde D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7a14840: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xf2c9ebe0)"

Comment: her is the complete code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ov5BesMJN7aXF9IGA-mJO0FObIqH4pWr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code.the permission for audio record is working fine.you have to also take external storage permission, to do this add this line to menifest file  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`.then change permission method to this

```
private void requestAudioPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO )
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

            } else {
                // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
            }
        }
        //If permission is granted, then go ahead recording audio
        else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Go ahead with recording audio now

        }
    }
```

and make another  the warning when click on microphone is from your website.check again in your site what is the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a microphone and camera directly with webView for that you need to add extra permissions MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and also RECORD_AUDIO as well then only you will be able to access the features.

Add these permissions in the manifest file using

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

then ask for permission using onPermissionRequest method in your webView client class.